# why it show empty object but still able to iterator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 4]
let key = arr.keys();

console.log(key);

for (const k of key) {
  console.log(k);
}
```

I'm getting confuse when I try to console `arr.keys()` it show me `undefined` but if there is nothing in it then how we can able to iterate that object that show me `0 1 2`.

Comment: @MaraBlack - Arrays [have a `keys` method now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys), added approximately six years ago.

Comment: *"I'm getting confuse when I try to console `arr.keys()` it show me `undefined`..."* It doesn't in the Stack Snippet Andy created by copying and pasting your code into [the editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/), and it certainly shouldn't. If you're doing this in the console, perhaps you got confused by an `undefined` from something else? (Such as a `console.log`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does not show undefined it shows

> Object [Array Iterator] {}, its not undefined but a iterator object
> when you do arr.keys() it simply makes an iterator of keys [0,1,2], in case of Simple integer or string arrays, index work as keys for example

```
const array = [34,45,67,89]
console.log(array[2]) // will print 67 as in current array at key 2 position it contains 67 value
```

if you want to print keys instead of iterator object you can use this code sample

```
let arr = [1,2,4]
let key = arr.keys();
console.log(key); // will print iterator object i.e Object [Array Iterator] {}
console.log([...key])  //shows [0,1,2], iterator is converted to simple array which you can print
```

Answer (score 1):

You've said

> why it show empty object but still able to iterator?

in the title but

> I'm getting confuse when I try to console `arr.keys()` it show me `undefined`

in the question. Those are very different things. It shows you an empty object, **not** `undefined`.

When you look at the iterator from `keys`, it doesn't have any properties or methods of its own, it inherits all of them from its prototype. So if the console you're using shows just the object's own properties (like the Stack Snippets console does), it'll look like an empty object.

But it still has state (just not state stored as "own" properties), and it still has the methods that an iterator is expected to have (it inherits them from its prototype). So it fulfills the "interface" of an iterator and works with `for-of`.

Here's an example of an iterator that works the same way. This is **not** how the array iterator is defined (though it's not a million miles off), it's just an example of an iterator with no "own" properties or methods that nonetheless is an iterator:

```js
function* iteratorForKeys(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        yield i;
    }
}

let keys = iteratorForKeys(["a", "b", "c"]);
console.log(keys); // Empty object if you ignore the prototype
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(keys).length); // 0
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(keys).length); // 0
console.log("Key values:");
for (const key of keys) {
    console.log(key);
}
```